cannot create cluster in AWS Amazon Elastic Container Service
I am trying to create a cluster in AWS Amazon Elastic Container Service, so a clicked on create cluster button, entered "defaut" as name and default namespace and with AWS Fargate (serveless) ticked, and when I click create button, I have the following error message:
There was an error creating cluster default.
Stack [Infra-ECS-Cluster-default-7505d64a] already exists
For my point of view, it means that this cluster already exists, However, when I try to inspect the created cluster, the drop box with existing cluster is empty. Can you help me ?
Here is a screen shot

It seems like the CloudFormation stack associated with your cluster name already exists, which is causing the error. To resolve this issue:

Navigate to the AWS CloudFormation console.
Locate the stack with the name matching your cluster (e.g., Infra-ECS-Cluster-default-7505d64a).
Delete this stack.
After the stack is deleted, try creating your cluster again.

This should allow you to create the cluster without encountering the error.

Hello aditya, thank you it works
